# Can't write into a .txt file (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm making a program where everytime you open the program there's a new randomized pin, but I need to be able to acces the pin inside the .txt file while the python program is running, but when I try to acces the entry pin while the program is running, it isn't there until after I close the program and the .txt file. Here's the piece of code I'm having problems with. (P.S. I added sleep to the end for testing)

```
import secrets
import string
from time import sleep

# define the alphabet
letters = string.ascii_letters
digits = string.digits

alphabet = letters + digits

# fix password length
pwd_length = 7

# generate a password string
pwd = ''
for i in range(pwd_length):
  pwd += ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet))

# generate password meeting constraints
while True:
  pwd = ''
  for i in range(pwd_length):
    pwd += ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet))

  if (any(char in letters for char in pwd) and 
      sum(char in digits for char in pwd)>=3):
          break

f= open("Random Entry Code.txt","w+")

for i in range(1):
     f.write (pwd + "%d\r\n" % (i+1))
sleep(10)
```

If you know how to fix this, please help me.

I tried to open the .txt file while the code is running multiple times, but it doesn't add the acces code to the .txt file until after the program is closed along with the .txt file.

Comment: You open the file in w+ mode presumably because you want to read from it after writing. If you want to do that, make sure you flush and truncate after the write

Comment: Is there any reason for a loop that only runs once (`for i in range(1):`)?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to close your file handler at the end.

```
f.close()
```

To be honest a better way of writing this code block would be to use a `with open` block. That way the file closure happens when the block exits. The [following documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) on the python website will help explain it.

This would look something like:

```
with open("Random Entry Code.txt","w+") as f:
    for i in range(1):
        f.write (pwd + "%d\r\n" % (i+1))
```